# Python Pandas: Selection of Columns by Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am able to select columns of a Pandas DataFrame with their positions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "c": [7, 8, 9],
                   "d": [10, 11, 12], "e": [13, 14, 15]})
df.iloc[:, 1:4]
```

With this, I can select the columns `b` up to `d`.

Is there any easy way I can do this using the column names?
Something like:

```
df.SOME_FUNCTION_OR_A_SPECIFIC_SYNTAX("b", "d")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `loc` only with `:` for range of columns:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, 'b':'d']
print (df1)

   b  c   d
0  4  7  10
1  5  8  11
2  6  9  12
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can also use `regex`:

```
df = df.filter(regex='[b-d]')
```

Or more general, specifying the column's name:

```
df = df[['b','c','d']]
```

Comment: I like it!  Nice answer.